# How to get input from user with c/c++ (for operating system)

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, kernel

I am writing an operating system with C++ to learn (INCLUDING C) I learned a few functions such as printing to the screen, but I could not learn to receive input from the user and print to the screen. I looked at many sources, but I could not find what I wanted.
What I want is to receive input from the user and print it on the screen and wait for a certain key to be pressed for an action. How can I do it?
I will be glad if you can provide sample code.

**loader.s**

```
.set MAGIC, 0x1badb002
.set FLAGS, (1<<0 | 1<<1)
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
    .long MAGIC
    .long FLAGS
    .long CHECKSUM
    


.section .text
.extern kernelMain
.extern callConstructors
.global loader

loader:
    mov $kernel_stack, %esp
    call callConstructors
    push %eax
    push %ebx
    call kernelMain

_stop:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp _stop


.section .bss 
.space 2*1024*1024;
kernel_stack:
```

**kernel.cpp**

```
#include "includes/types.h"
#include "includes/functions.h"
#include "includes/colors.h"
#include "includes/keyboard.h"
using namespace std;

typedef void (*constructor)();
extern "C" constructor* start_ctors;
extern "C" constructor* end_ctors;
extern "C" void callConstructors()
{
    for(constructor* i=start_ctors;i!=end_ctors;i++){
        (*i)();
    }
}

extern "C" void kernelMain(void* multiboot_structure, uint32_t magicnumber)
{ 
    print(COLOR_RED, "Hello!");
    while(1);
}
```

**functions.h**

```
#include "keyboard.h"
#include "colors.h"


static unsigned short* VideoMemory=(unsigned short*)0xb8000;

int pos_print = 0;

void print_title( unsigned char colour, const char *string) {
    volatile unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VideoMemory;
    while(*string != 0)
    {
        *(vid) = *string;
        *(vid+1) = colour;
        ++string;
        vid+=2;
    }
}


void setChar(char character, short col, short row, unsigned char attr) {
    volatile unsigned char* vid_mem = (unsigned char *) VideoMemory;
    int offset = (row*80 + col)*2;
    vid_mem += offset;
    if(!attr) {
        attr = 0x0f;
    }
    *(unsigned short int *)vid_mem = (attr<<8)+character;
}

void print_line( unsigned char colour, const char *string, int pos ) {
    volatile unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VideoMemory;
    vid+=pos*160;
    while(*string != 0)
    {
        *vid = *string;
        *(vid+1) = colour;
        ++string;
        vid+=2;
    }

}

void print( unsigned char colour, char string ) {
    volatile unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VideoMemory;
    pos_print+=1;
    vid+=pos_print*160;
    while(string != 0)
    {
        *vid = string;
        *(vid+1) = colour;
        ++string;
        vid+=2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Look into interrupts, after you setup IDT and enable PIC, you should be able to handle IRQ1, which is PS/2 port. That includes PS/2 keyboard. If your hardware can emulate it, that's probably the easiest way to set it up.

Comment: @Kaihaku like i said i'm new and i don't know how to do it, can you post a source that explains it simply?

Comment: Check out the [OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) site, it has lots of information about [interrupts](https://wiki.osdev.org/Babystep5) and other OSDev related things.

Comment: Can I do it by writing assembly code inside the __asm__ function?